# 18 digit timestamp?

Tags: php, xml, timestamp

I am working on a system related to tv recordings.

I am parsing the following xml from another system (to which i have no documentation):

```
<Program FileName="2009.11.07-Saturday 07 November 2009.dvr-ms" SubChannel="ABC1" StartTime="633931722046825183" StopTime="633932388000119414" ActualStopTime="633932388016825183" ShareShow="True" />
<Program FileName="2009.11.08-Sunday 08 November 2009.dvr-ms" SubChannel="ABC1" StartTime="633932586046773253" StopTime="633933252000157907" ActualStopTime="633933252006773253" ShareShow="True" />
<Program FileName="2009.11.09-Monday 09 November 2009.dvr-ms" SubChannel="ABC1" StartTime="633933450046168953" StopTime="633934116000207688" ActualStopTime="633934116026168953" ShareShow="True" />
<Program FileName="2009.11.10-Tuesday 10 November 2009.dvr-ms" SubChannel="ABC1" StartTime="633934314046899495" StopTime="633934980000869533" ActualStopTime="633934980096899495" ShareShow="True" />
<Program FileName="2009.11.11-Wednesday 11 November 2009.dvr-ms" SubChannel="ABC1" StartTime="633935178054202612" StopTime="633935844000077447" ActualStopTime="633935844064202612" ShareShow="True" />
<Program FileName="2009.11.12-Thursday 12 November 2009.dvr-ms" SubChannel="ABC1" StartTime="633936042047633656" StopTime="633936708000009191" ActualStopTime="633936708047633656" ShareShow="True" />
```

My question is, does anyone recognise the timestamp format of the StartTime and StopTime attributes? I thought typically timestamps to the second had 10 digits, so where are the other 8 coming from? My guess is something like timezone and millisecond accuracy.

I am using php, so a php specific way of converting it to a datetime would be nice, but anything is good.

Comment: Timestamps counting milliseconds from epoch currently have 10 digits. Once there were 3/4/5/6/etc digits to a "now" timestamp.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It looks like C#'s DateTime ticks:

> The DateTime value type represents
>   dates and times with values ranging
>   from 12:00:00 midnight, January 1,
>   0001 Anno Domini (Common Era) through
>   11:59:59 P.M., December 31, 9999 A.D.
>   (C.E.)

This line:

```
Console.WriteLine (new DateTime (633936042047633656));
```

prints:

> 11/12/2009 6:30:04 AM

If you need to convert from those numbers to Unix time, substract 621355968000000000L, which is the Unix epoch expressed in *ticks*.

Comment: Hmm, with no 64 bit int in PHP that could be an issue :P Oh well, i'll find a way.

Comment: Shouldn't be too hard to do that math in 32 bits, with a bit of string preprocessing. First "divide" by a million by removing the last 6 characters of the string, then remove the leading "6". Next subtract 2 from the first digit of the string. Now convert what's left to a 32 bits integer, and subtract 1355968000.

Answer (score 2):

With the gmp lib installed in php you can do it like this:

```
$epoch     = '621355968000000000';
$newtime   = gmp_sub($dateTime, $epoch);
$newtime   = gmp_div($newtime, '10000000');
$timestamp = gmp_strval($newtime);
```

and now you got a date:

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$dateLargeInt= "131424999530821857";
$secsAfterADEpoch = $dateLargeInt / (10000000); 
$ADToUnixConvertor=((1970-1601) * 365.242190) * 86400;
// unix epoch - AD epoch * number of tropical days * seconds in a day 
$unixTsLastLogon=intval($secsAfterADEpoch-$ADToUnixConvertor); 

// unix Timestamp version of AD timestamp
$lastlogon=date("d-m-Y", $unixTsLastLogon); // formatted date

echo $lastlogon;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", (strtotime("01/01/0001 00:00:00 UTC") + (634019142119225390 / 10000000)));
```

simple but works

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).