# unix timestamp conversion showing wrong dates

Tags: mysql, sql

Can someone guide me to convert timestamp. I am able to convert using various formulas like below, but it shows wrong dates. For example the timestamp 136006971590000000 I know is between October 10th and October 12th 2013, but it shows Feb 2013. I am using DBISQL (sybase). Below are some of the queries I am using but none of them show correct time.

1. select 
   dateadd(ms, 136006971590000000-(1360069715900/1000)*1000,
   dateadd(ss, 1360069715900000000/1000+8*60*60, '19700101'))
2. select dateadd(second, 136006971590000000/100000000+8*60*60,  '19700101')

Comment: UNIX timestamps are 10 digits. The ones you provide seem a little long

Comment: Where did you get the timestamp from? It's *not* a Unix timestamp in the normal sense - either in seconds, milliseconds or microseconds. (In microseconds since the Unix epoch, it's Feb 2013.)

Comment: Thanks Cillier, I tried that too. Still shows Feb 2013.

Comment: Jon, This is where I am perplexed. I am using DBI SQL which is Sybase tool

Comment: I am pulling starttime and endtime between Oct1oth and Oct12th which gives me starttime 136006971590000000. Now, I convert the same time using the above query and it shows Feb2013.

Comment: If you are using Sybase, why did you tag your question with `mysql`? That's a completely different product.

Answer (score 0):

could your 18 digit timestamps be LDAP & Active Directory Timestamps ?? 
(from google search for 18 digit timestamp)

I found this here:  [18 digit timestamp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832714/18-digit-timestamp)

If you need to convert from those numbers to Unix time, subtract 621355968000000000L, which is the Unix epoch expressed in ticks.

Comment: Thank you BWS. Do you have a complete query by any chance? I googled 18 digit timestamp and got online converter. It shows GMT: Sun, 28 Dec 2031 11:25:59 GMT.                        http://www.epochconverter.com/epoch/ldap-timestamp.php

Comment: did this link help?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832714/18-digit-timestamp